# Redirect user to previous page after login in Django-allauth social Facebook login

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using Django-allauth for social login. I am using method="js_sdk" . So it gives a popup for login. But it's redirecting to profile page or home page if specified in settings. Is there a way to redirect to the previous page on which user was original. For example, if I have a page https://www.example.com/product/t-shirsts-black/  so when user log in it should redirect to this page. I have read the docs but it seems they have missed it.